# How to handle Symbol not find Error?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am writing a program for registration form in java and I've created the connection class separately.But while compiling my register.java class I'm getting symbol not found error. Please check if anyone could help .

This is the code for my Connection class.

```
import java.sql.*;
class JDBCConnection
{
Connection con=null;
public Connection getConnection()
{
try
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","cloud","cloud");

}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
{
    ce.printStackTrace();

}
catch(SQLException sqe)
{
        sqe.printStackTrace();
}
return con;
    }
   }
```

And code for the Register class is as follows :

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Register1 extends HttpServlet
{       
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws  IOException

{
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    String str= req.getParameter("First");
    String str1 = req.getParameter("Last");
    String str2=req.getParameter("Uname");
    String str3=req.getParameter("Month");
    String day=req.getParameter("Day");
    String year=req.getParameter("Year");
    String str4=req.getParameter("Gen");
    String str5=req.getParameter("Phone");
    String str6=req.getParameter("Mail");




    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<form action=\"../Page(1).html\">");

    JDBCConnection obj=new JDBCConnection();
    Connection con=obj.getConnection();
    String query="insert into Register values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    int i=0;
    try
    {
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, str);
        ps.setString(2, str1);
        ps.setString(3, str2);
        ps.setString(4, day);
        ps.setString(5,str3);
        ps.setString(6,year);
        ps.setString(7,str4);
        ps.setString(8,str5);
        ps.setString(9,str6);
      i=ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(i==1)
        {
        res.sendRedirect("../Page(1).html");
       }
    out.println("</html>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</form >");

}

   }
```

The Error is as Follows :

```
    Register1.java:32:error: cannot find symbol
                    JDBCConnection obj=new JDBCConnection();
                    ^  
    symbol:  class JDBCConnection
    location: class Register1
    Register1.java:32:error: cannot find symbol
                    JDBCConnection obj=new JDBCConnection();
                                           ^
    symbol:  class JDBCConnection
    location: class Register1
    2 Errors
```

Comment: Are these classes in their own packages or the default package?

Comment: They are in default package @JonK

Answer (score 1):

Java does not automatically include the current current directory in the classpath when a dependent JAR is specified, therefore it needs to be added

```
javac -cp .:servlet-api.jar *.java
```

Comment: The OP wrote the `JDBCConnection` class themselves, so why would including the servlet-api.jar on the classpath fix this problem?

Comment: Its likely that `servlet-api.jar` is being specified on the CP which causes the current path not to be included automatically

Comment: I included current directory in the classpath and don't know but it worked. Thanks @Reimeus

Comment: But the same program was working fine without adding the current directory in classpath in other computer but not in mine. How's that possible ?

Comment: Perhaps the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable was set on that other machine